# How to apply a color to the SystemTray globaly in wp7?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I already know how to set the color for the SystemTray in WP7, I was just wondering if there was a way to change it in one place and have it applied to all pages instead of having to explicitly set the color on every page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a Application Resource for the color and then you could apply this color resource in every page you have with Binding.

Or you could use MVVM and have a property in your ViewModel and Bind to this property.